# Withdrawal from Poloniex have not shown in my ether wallet

Tags: myetherwallet, poloniex

I have made a withdrawal from poloniex 2 days ago. withdrawal status shows complete with TX ID but eth never arrive in myetherwallet. i see multiple users have complaint the same thing. i have been doing few withdrawals last week with no problem. is this because of the ICO thing. Any thoughts?

P/S i did open a support ticket 2 days ago.

Thanks guys! really appreciate your help.

UPDATE: GOOD NEWS! I HAVE RECEIVED ALL MY ETH IN MYETHERWALLET.

Comment: What is the TX ID showing in etherscan ? Can you see it as a pending transaction or is there no record ?

Comment: i have check the TX ID given but there is no record in etherscan. Please advice.

Comment: UPDATE: GOOD NEWS! I HAVE RECEIVED ALL MY ETH IN MYETHERWALLET.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer with details that you can add.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dashforcenews.com/ico-mania-grinds-ethereum-halt-scaling-issues-not-limited-bitcoin/ I think this might explain it.

Comment: Yes. Ico mania is now on ethereum network. i really hope poloniex could fix the problem asap or maybe give some updates on the site.